# Ordered directional constrained connection of points for maximum triangles

Tags: javascript, graph, path, notation

**Begin Edit**
Given a set of points,
each defined by latitude and longitude,
find an ordered list of directional connections between points within three points that form a triangle such that connecting inner points of that triangle with each other and these three points produces maximum triangles, with the following constraints:

- The connection of two points is directional, and the number of outgoing connections can be up to the value of some variable `maxOutgoing`, and the length of each outgoing connection can be up to the value of some variable `maxOutgoingLength`.  Incoming count and length is not limited.
- Connections may **not** cross each other.
- To each point we may apply a combination of up to **four** modifiers:

  - `increaseOutgoing` that increases the number of outgoing by the value of some constant `increaseOutgoingBy`, and
  - `increaseOutgoingLength` that increases the length of the outgoing connection by the value of some constant `increaseOutgoingLengthBy`.
- Order of connection is **important**:
  Once a point is enclosed in a triangle, no more outgoing connections can be made.

In the original form of this question, I wanted to find a unique "path" and "notation" for each of the solution's participating points.
**End Edit**

Intro:

I have a recursive function that finds centers of given three points.
I start with vertices a, b, and c.
The center is labeled (abc).
The center splits triangle abc into three triangles: (abc)ab, (abc)ac, and (abc)bc, with centers: ((abc)ab), ((abc)ac), and ((abc)bc).  And so on.
My function sorts the vertices' names - parentheses character codes are smaller than letters, that's why ((abc)ab) and not, for example, (ab(abc)).
I've noticed that each point has a unique count of a's, b's, and c's (as well as parentheses, which can be ignored).

Looking for:

A way to visually (I can, and do, draw the triangles: each vertex to the other two and to the center) get to a point given it's name, but it can get very long, so, perhaps, use letter-count.  For example: point (((abc)ab)((abc)a((abc)ab))((abc)((abc)ab)((abc)a((abc)ab)))) has a, b, and c letter-count of 13, 11, and 7, and to get to it, assuming a is top vertex, b is below a and to the right, and c is below a and to the left (just for example.  they can be in any order/direction), we (1) go to the center, (2) then right-up-right, (3) then left-up-left, (4) then down-right-down, and, finally, (5) right-up-right - all along drawn lines (green path in image below).

How to get these directions from the point's name/letter-count?!? Instead of painfully dissecting the point's name and using pencil and paper...

Ignore the grey lines in the image below.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, your explanation leaves the basic problem insufficiently defined.  First of all, *which* [center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_center) are you using?  Your illustration uses an isosceles triangle that is nearly equilateral; this obfuscates the issue.  You've also obfuscated the construction of the center; the process would help us differentiate.

Comment: Also, your desired output is unclear.  You appear to want a sequence of directions such as "up-left-up", but you don't explain the rationale behind the notation: why "up-left-up" instead of "up-up-left"?  Why not just "up-left"?  Also note that, for some triangles and some center definitions, this is not sufficient to choose the desired path.

Comment: up-left-up as in a map: East-North-East.
more up then up-left: more east than north-east.
in the first part, i explain that each point except the outer vertices, are centers of 3 points, starting with the outer vertices.
in the second part, i mean the main center = the center of the outer vertices.

Comment: Okay: for *direction*, you want the nearest of the 16 principal points of the compass.  For *center*, my question still stands.  Please consult the link I provided.  There is no "main center" in geometric terminology.

Comment: My "center" may start as a centroid and can be changed to any point INSIDE same inner-triangle, so, "center" reads: a point inside a triangle (but not on any edge).
My "Main Center" is the center (as re-defined before) of the outermost triangle.
In Euclidean geometry, I could find any point by it's (x,y) coordinates, and compared to the center = (0,0), I could determine in which quadrant a point is by it's signs.
My triangles and centers HAVE Euclidean values, but instead of quadrants, I have tridrants(?!?!?) and the main (outer) triangle can be any size, type, orientation...

Answer (score 0):

In that case, the answer is simply (and trivially) "no".  If "center" is so loosely restricted, then it is not possible to determine the direction of a center from the previous one.  Consider your drawing, for example, starting from that first center.  Your definition restricts the next center only to be in the triangle's interior.  Thus, the directionality can be anything from RDR to UUU (with only a smidgen to the right).

Your notation is sufficient to uniquely denote any particular sub-triangle in the hierarchy.  Without a definition of "center", you don't have enough information to guarantee even the cardinal direction of the center.